# How do I set up a public server on a network?

Tags: router, ip-address, webserver, ubuntu-server, lamp

I am trying to set up a personal cloud server with OwnCloud on Ubuntu. LAMP is all set up. I was able to access it using the external IP address when I connected it directly to the modem, but what if I what if I want my server to share a LAN? I still want it accessible over the internet, but then if I go to the IP address from a web browser, it just tries to log into to router admin tools. The internal IP address works across the LAN, but I want to be able to access it from anywhere.

This may be simple and I may be over-thinking it, but how do access my server?

The router I am using is ASUS WL-520GU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure "port forwarding" in your router. HTTP usually uses 80/tcp. Note that you'll probably still have to use the internal address to access it on the LAN, since most routers assume that you want to access the admin interface if you go to any of the router's addresses from the inside.

Comment: But anywhere outside my network it will be mapped to my server?

Comment: Correct. The router figures out that it's not from an internal address and forwards it properly.